# PHP - Check a value inside txt file if already exist

Tags: php

HTML Code:

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">  
<label for="id-group">ID Gruppo</label>
<input type="text" id="id-group" name="id-group" />  
<br>
<label for="group-name">Nome del Gruppo</label>  
<input type="text" id="group-name" name="group-name" />  
<br>
<input type="submit" name="inserisci" value="Inserisci" />  
</form> 

<div style="width:400px;height:400px;background:green;">
<?php
$groups_database = 'groups.txt';
$riga = file($groups_database);
foreach($riga as $groups){
list($id, $nome_gruppo) = explode("|", $groups);
echo'
<div style="text-align:center;">
<a href="javascript:;" onClick="window.open(\'https://m.facebook.com/groups/'.$id.'?view=info\',\'TITLE\',\'toolbar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no, top=10, left=50, width=500, height=700\');">'.$nome_gruppo.'</a></br>
</div>';
}
?>
</div>
```

This is my code to write two value inside a txt database:
(insert.php)

```
<?php
$bad_char = array("|");
$id = str_replace($bad_char, "", $_POST['id-group']);
$group = str_replace($bad_char, "", $_POST['group-name']);
$open = fopen("groups.txt","a+");
fwrite($open, $id."|".$group."\n");
fclose($open);
header("location: /");
exit;
?>
```

Now, i'm wondering how i can check if a value its already present in the database, and if already present, get an alert message (not an ugly echo msg).
Sorry, i'm a beginner with php...
Hope in your help. Regards.

Comment: Mayby you should consider use CSV file format? There is example of using this format in PHP: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php10p6.html. It's make working with data stored in files in more convenient and easier way.

Comment: read in the file, explode() it, check the resulting array for your value...

Comment: what *are* you looking for?

Comment: Show what is in `$_POST` variable.

Comment: For the 1st part of your question, use a format designed for structured data, such as json. For the second, please clarify what you mean by alert message vs echo message. Probably you just need to style an html element with css

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<?php
session_start();

$id = preg_replace( '~\|~', '', $_POST['id-group']);
$group = preg_replace( '~\|~', '', $_POST['group-name']);
$messages = [];

$handle = @fopen("groups.txt","r+");
if( $handle )
{
    $i = 1;
    $exists = 0;
    while(( $str = fgets($handle)) !== false)
    {
      if( $id."|".$group."\n" === $str)
      {
        $exists ++;
      }
      $str = preg_replace( '~[^\|]~', '', $str);
      if( 1 !== strlen( $str ))
      {
        $messages [] = 'Line number ' . $i . ' - incorrect format';
      }
      $i++;
    }
    if ( ! feof($handle)) {
      $messages [] = 'fgets() error occured';
    }
    if( $exists )
    {
      $messages [] = 'Group already exists';
    } else {
      fwrite( $handle, $id."|".$group."\n");
    }
    fclose( $handle);
    if( ! empty( $messages))
    {
      $_SESSION ['errors'] = $messages;
    }
}

header("location: /");
exit();
?>
```

And inside '/' route:

```
<?php
session_start();
if( isset( $_SESSION ['errors'] ) && is_array( $_SESSION ['errors']))
{
  echo "<h2>Errors:</h2>";
  foreach( $_SESSION ['errors'] as $mess)
  {
    echo "<h3>{$mess}</h3>";
  }
  unset( $_SESSION ['errors']);
}
?>
```

Comment: But a better way is a filter the `$_POST` variables and throw error message if is incorrect chars has been detected

Comment: I have update my entire code: html and php i'm using.
What's the mean for "And inside '/' route:" ?

Comment: script which is run then **http://your-site.com/** url is requested. You redirect to a '/' url at the end of our first script. Usualy it is **index.php** script.

Comment: Insert second script before `<form action="insert.php" method="post">`

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '&&' (T_BOOLEAN_AND) in in the index.php

Comment: anyway, your script doesn't write in the TXT... not work :( . Can't you simply edit the code up in the question?

Comment: `doesn't write in the TXT...` It's not possible to correct a wrong record, because script dont know where is the error if there are several '|' in the line. It's handmake job.

Comment: and why my short php is working fine? Miss only a part to check inside the database if something is already present... I don't think its impossible to do...

Comment: Sorry, i think you need to check previous records for invalid simbols :-)
Try again - script 1 corrected

Comment: Nothing again...not work. But sorry, why don't you edit starting from my code? Its so small and simple... :(